# Entity Framework ExecuteStoreCommand

Tags: frameworks, entity

I am trying to use Entity framework. I also need to query catalog tables for which I am trying to use ExecuteStoreCommand - but it is not populating the records.

Here is the code

```
[Table("INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS")]
public class CatalogColumnDef
{
    private string tableCatalog;

    [Column("TABLE_CATALOG")]
    public string TableCatalog
    {
        get { return tableCatalog; }
        set { tableCatalog = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ToStringBuilder.ReflectionToString(this);
    }
}
```

}

ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
            objectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("use AdventureWorks");
            var result = objectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery("select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Personn'");

It gets the records but the field value tableCatalog is set to null. Why is it not able to populate the values correctly?